# How do I check the existence of a table using a variable as tablename

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

a) checks a table to find names of other tables that need to be created
b) check if that table already exists
c) if not, create it
d) fill her up with new data

Now, this all works fine up to the part that has to check whether the table exists:

```
set @NewTablename = (select NAME from SomeTable where ID= @i)
set @Tabelexists = 'select case when exists(select * from sys.tables where name = ''' + @NewTabelname + ''') then 1 else 0 end'

declare @check as int execute(@Tabelexists)

IF    @check is NULL 
BEGIN
Create Table
END
ELSE
BEGIN
execute('Delete from '+ @NewTableName)
END

<other stuff like inserts and so on)
```

But somehow, @check always seems to be NULL when the table does not exist, and to 1 if it does.

If I check for `IF @check is null` only the TRUE part is executed if the table does not exist. If it *does* exist at that moment *nothing* is executed.....

If I check for `IF @check =1`  only the ELSE is executed

The value of @check  apparently is always either NULL or 1 or 0..........

I am at a loss here! 
How do I check the existence of a table using a variable as tablename?

Damien, I understand what you are saying. But if I do it like this I still have no result I can test:

`declare  @check as int execute ('select case when exists(select * from sys.tables where name = ''' + @Tabelnaam + ''') then 1 else 0 end')`

Comment: Damien, I understand what you are saying. But if I do it like this I still have no result I can test:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking the sys tables for the existence of something I always tend to select a count(*) that way the answer is always 0 or positive and I then use that number accordingly.

```
SELECT @Tabelexists = count(*) FROM sys.tables where name = ''' + @NewTabelname +''')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could check like this

```
if not exists(select * from sys.tables where  type='u' and name = @NewTabelname ) 
BEGIN
Create Table
END
ELSE
BEGIN
execute('Delete from '+ @NewTableName)
END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @check as tinyint

set @NewTablename = (select NAME from SomeTable where ID= @i)
select @check=1 from sys.tables where name = @NewTabelname
```

or

```
set @NewTablename = (select NAME from SomeTable where ID= @i)
IF  not exists(select * from sys.tables where name = @NewTabelname)    
...
```

Comment: This was it.................... There was no need for the execute statement at all! Thanks!